# Почему слетели скрипты и шейдеры при загрузке сцены из ассет бандла?

Tags: unity3d, assets

При загрузке сцены из ассет бандла, который я скачиваю из CDN, слетают все скрипты и шейдеры. Однако, собрав бандл и запустив из него сцену (без этапа подгрузки с CDN) все хорошо встает.[image: 17 слетевших скриптов и сами материалы, сцена подгружена с CDN]

В чем может быть причина, в манифесте?
Если нет, то в какую сторону копать?